# At most countably many mutually disjoint Borel sets have nonzero $\mu$-measure

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification

I'm proving this lemma

> If $\mu$ is a finite Borel measure on a metric space $X$ and $\mathcal{A}$ a collection of mutually disjoint Borel sets of $X$, then at most countably many elements of $\mathcal{A}$ have nonzero $\mu$-measure.

This boils down to below result.

> Let $(a_i)_{i\in I}$ be a collection of non-negative real numbers. Let's define $$\sum_{i\in I} a_i := \sup \left \{\sum_{i\in J} a_i \,\middle\vert\, J \text{ is a countable subset of } I \right\}.$$ If $\sum_{i\in I} a_i < \infty$, then at most countably many $a_i$'s are positive.

Could you have a check on my attempt?

---

Let $J := \{i \in I \mid a_i >0\}$ and $J_r := \{i\in I \mid a_i \ge r\}$ for $r \in \mathbb Q_{>0}$. Then $$J= \bigcup_{r\in \mathbb Q_{>0}} J_r.$$

It follows from $\sum_{i\in I} a_i < \infty$ that $J_r$ is countable for all $r\in \mathbb Q_{>0}$. Then it follows from $\mathbb Q_{>0}$ is countable that $J$ is countable.

Comment: Your proof is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof is correct.

Mind, each $J_r$ is not only countable, but actually finite.